# How to get date & time of received outlook mail and check body from particular sender using python

Tags: python, loops, datetime, email, outlook

I am trying to achieve the following using python:
*get the last 24hrs outlook inbox mails from the particular sender and checking if a particular text is  presented in the body of that email*

below is I tried :

```
import sys, win32com.client, datetime
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
s = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Items   
# Get yesterdays date for the purpose of getting emails from this date
d = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta (days=1)).strftime("%d-%m-%y")
# get the email/s
msg = s.GetLast()
# Loop through emails
while msg:
    # Get email date 
    date = msg.SentOn.strftime("%d-%m-%y")
    # Set the critera for whats wanted                       
    if (d == date) and ("MAINTENANCE" in msg.body) and ("Upgrade" in msg.Subject) and msg.Sender == "aa@bb.com" :
        print("Date : ", date) 
    msg = s.GetPrevious()
```

error :

> date = msg.SentOn.strftime("%d-%m-%y")   File
> "C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py",
> line 527, in **getattr**
> raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self.*username*, attr)) AttributeError: GetPrevious.SentOn

and notsure what is the error in the checking line

```
if (d == date) and ("MAINTENANCE" in msg.body) and ("Upgrade" in msg.Subject) and msg.Sender == "aa@bb.com" :
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, never loop through *all* item in a folder - you wouldn't use a SELECT statement in SQL without a WHERE clause, would you? Always use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`.

Secondly, `Sender` is not a scalar (string) property - it returns an object (`AddressEntry`), so what you want is `MailItem.Sender.Address` (after checking that `MailItem.Sender` is no null).

Thirdly, besides `MailItem` objects in your Inbox folder, you can also have other items, such as `MeetingItem` and `ReportItem` whcih may not expose all the properties you are accessing (such as `Sender`) . If you only want `MailItem` objects, check that the `Class` property (exposed by all OOM objects) == 43 (`OlObjectClass.olMail`).